# bsxfun() Invalid output dimensions

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a function that takes upto seven arguments and returns a row vector. The first three arguments are vectors (column, column, row) and the remaining four are optional scalars.

I want to use `bsxfun()` to apply the function to a vector of its last argument. Below is my attempt to do that.

```
o = @(m,pulse,N0,samples_per_pulse,sample_select,filter,channel_cutoff) ELE452Functions.EvaluateBER(m,pulse,N0,samples_per_pulse,sample_select,filter,channel_cutoff);
oo = @(m,pulse,N0,samples_per_pulse,sample_select,filter,channel_cutoff) bsxfun(@(N0,channel_cutoff) o(m,pulse,N0,samples_per_pulse,sample_select,filter,channel_cutoff), N0' , channel_cutoff);
```

when I try to call the function with a vector, `oo(m,pulse,N0,1,1,1,[0.5 0.2]);` for example, I get this error:

```
Error using bsxfun
Invalid output dimensions.
```

I am not experienced in using bsxfun and I tried to follow the documentation.

Update:

May be this is a clearer way to ask my question:
I want to use bsxfun to rewrite (improve) the code below with out a loop.

```
for i=1:length(channel_normalized_cuttoffs)
    BER_LPchannel(i,:) = ELE452Functions.EvaluateBER(m,pulse,N0,1,1,1,channel_normalized_cuttoffs(i));
end
```

Comment: What exactly is that `ELE452Functions.EvaluateBER`?

Comment: EvaluateBER is a function from the ELE452Functions class. It is in a separate m file.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `permute` there to "send" `channel_cutoff` to the third dim - `bsxfun(........permute(channel_cutoff(:),[3 2 1]))`.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I see you are trying to apply what you just learned about `bsxfun`. ;-)
By the way: Your first line of code can be simplified to:
`o = @ELE452Functions.EvaluateBER`. You don't need to enter all the arguments if you just want ALL of them.

Comment: Could you share the function `ELE452Functions.EvaluateBER` with us? We could dig deeper into it for a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind `bsxfun` is to evaluate a certain function for all possible combinations of two elements (`b` in `bsxfun` stands for *binary*), each coming from one of the arrays. (NB: This is valid if you use it with a row and a column vector. But `bsxfun` can also do more.)

What you want to achieve is simply: For all entries of a single array, evaluate a function.
So `bsxfun` is just not the correct choice here.

You could use [`arrayfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) instead, but this still may not perform a lot better than your original for loop, as it looks like the Matlab JIT Compiler would be able to optimize most of it, considering it's simplicity.

As I don't have the code of your function, I'm not able to test it, but your solution might look a lot like this:

```
evalBER = @(CNcutoffi) ELE452Functions.EvaluateBER(m,pulse,N0,1,1,1,CNcutoffi);
BER_LPchannel = arrayfun(evalBER, channel_normalized_cuttoffs, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: arrayfun(evalBER, channel_normalized_cuttoffs, 'UniformOutput', false) worked. thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you time it using `tic` and `toc`? I'd be interested in the time difference compared to the `for` loop.

Comment: Sure. The for loop took 7.312199 seconds, and your code took 6.897681.

Comment: Ok. As suspected, to really speed things up you would have to dig into the function `EvaluateBER` itself...

Comment: I did, the bottlenecks are the eyediagram() function (41% time) and randn() (17% time) and conv() (8% time).